# React.js website build works on one host, but not another

Tags: react-router-dom

I am new to react.js . I have created a react website using create-rect-app. I have run: npm run build in git and got my static site files. Everything works on the test host, however when i moved hosts only index page works and navigating to other page gives 404 error. For routing im using react-router-dom.

How can i get my page to work on the other host?

Working host: http://000webhost.com/
Badly working host is some local provider

Edit: Basically i have pages such as /Home and /Contact.
Im using react-router-dom.

code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import Home from './pages/Home.jsx';
import Contacts from './pages/Contacts.jsx';
import Our_products from './pages/Our_products.jsx';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path ="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path ="/Home" component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path ="/Contacts" component={Contacts}/>
          <Route exact path ="/Our-products" component={Our_products}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My index is linked to /Home as you can see from code. i have uploaded Build folder to public_html on both hosting platforms. On one site works normaly, on the other only /Home page shows up.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: Please remove `nodejs` and `git` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can ignore this, but what helped is changing

```html
<a href="/" />
```

to

```html
<Link to="/" />
```

. Basically one hosting provider could render links as

```html
<a />
```

other only as

```html
<Link />
```

Comment: What i actually needed when deploying was .htaccess file